# Can't debug Android: This device cannot start. (Code 10)

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I have a brand new Nexus One.  I'm trying to follow the directions for [installing the USB driver](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).  When I plug in the device, it doesn't start the New Hardware Wizard, as the documentation suggests.  I can run hdwwiz.exe to launch it and manually install the driver, but when I do, Device Manager says: "This device cannot start. (Code 10)"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duh.  I forgot to enable "USB Debugging" in Settings -> Applications -> Development.  As soon as I did that, the New Hardware Wizard appeared and installation went smoothly.

Comment: Conversely, I couldn't get the memory card to mount in Windows, and UNchecking USB Debugging allowed that to work.

Comment: USB Debugging on my device was already enabled. Disabled and re-enabled it and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you also have to install drivers. If you for example have a HTC those drivers are included in the HTC sync software.